# Formatting the string

Tags: python, string, list

```
'[0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217]'
```

how do i convert the  above string to list of elements using python as below.The element is float in below example.

```
[0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217]
```

```
"['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']"  #string
```

Also i need above example containing alphabets to list of alphabets as below.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `json` library to interpret the strings from json:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217]')
[0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217]
```

Comment: It's not going to work for the second example though.

Comment: my bad, good point. In theory, you could just replace all instances of `'` with `"`.